# Delphi Indy GMail security issues

Tags: delphi, email, gmail, indy

I have successfully sent email using GMail's SMTP server with the code below. I'm using Delphi 2006 and the latest version of Indy (10.6.2) and latest fulgan ssl libraries. The problem is that I had to turn down the GMail security settings as explained in the Google link. With the default high settings I get a cryptic error something like this: "https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?[...] Please log in via your web browser and then try again. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 [...] - gsmtp". How can I adjust the code below to use GMail's high security settings?

```
  IdSMTP1.host:='smtp.gmail.com';
  IdSMTP1.username:='[deleted]@gmail.com';
  IdSMTP1.Password:='[deleted]';
  IdSMTP1.port:=587;
  IdSMTP1.UseTLS:=utUseExplicitTLS;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Method:= sslvTLSv1;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 2;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Host := IdSMTP1.Host;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Port := IdSMTP1.Port;

  IdMessage1.From.address := '[deleted]@gmail.com';
  IdMessage1.CClist.EMailAddresses:= edit1.Text;
  IdMessage1.Subject:= 'Subject is here';
  IdMessage1.Body.Clear;
  Idmessage1.Body.Add('Body is here');
  IdSMTP1.Connect;
  try
    try
      idSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
    except on E:Exception do
      Memo1.Lines.Insert(0, 'ERROR: ' + E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    if idSMTP1.Connected then idSMTP1.Disconnect;
  end;
```

Comment: Which of the suggestions on the "Learn more" link have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you create an app-specific password and use **this specific** password?

Comment: @SirRufo you beat me to it...

Comment: @JerryDodge sorry :o)

Comment: So it's a GMail issue not an Indy issue? No one else has seemed to ever had such a problem before. My previous work with GMail never had this problem either. Maybe a new security policy? I don't seem to be allowed to create App passwords on my account. It says: "The setting that you are looking for is not available for your account.". I'll just tell the customer to turn on the "Access for less secure apps" setting then. That's pretty shady though.

Comment: Gmail recently made this a requirement to use their SMTP server. You need to A) Enable the 2-step verification, and B) Configure a unique application password dedicated to your app (and per machine too). It's not a flaw, bug, or issue. It's a security feature.

Comment: I can confirm that `TIdSMTP` does work with Gmail's *app password* feature, when enabled.